# how find out delegate return void ?

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, action, func

I want to know current delegate signature.

Especially I want to classify "Action" and "Func" deleagte.

like, if current delegate is action, run action and return current value,

and if func, run func and return result of func.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check whether a delegate returns void, you can check

```
bool isVoid = myDelegate.Method.ReturnType == typeof(void);
```

To specifically test whether a delegate is an `Action`, you can use

```
bool isActionT1_T2 = myDelegate.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Action<,>);
```

This will match any `Action<T1, T2>` (with two generic type arguments). You can do the same for `Func<T1, RetType>`, and with other argument counts.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is the best or only way, but if you have the *type* you could look for the `.Invoke` method:

```
Type type = ...
if(type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Delegate)))
{
    var method = type.GetMethod("Invoke");
    foreach(var arg in method.GetParameters())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg.Name + ": " + arg.ParameterType.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("returns: " + method.ReturnType.ToString())
}
```

The `.ReturnType` will be `typeof(void)` in your case.

---

If you have an *instance* of a delegate, you can do the same with the `.Method` property on the delegate itself:

```
Delegate instance = ...
var method = instance.Method;
foreach(var arg in method.GetParameters())
{
    Console.WriteLine(arg.Name + ": " + arg.ParameterType.ToString());
}
Console.WriteLine("returns: " + method.ReturnType.ToString());
```

---

re:

> like, if current delegate is action, run action and return current value,

You can special case that:

```
if(instance is Action) {
    ((Action)instance)();
} else {
    //...
}
```

However, you'll probably need to use `DynamicInvoke` a lot if dealing with arbitrary delegates.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
 static void InspectDelegate(object obj)
 {
     if (!(obj is Delegate del))
         return;
     var returnType = del.Method.ReturnType.Name;
     var parameters = del.Method.GetParameters();
     Dictionary<string, string> argNames = 
                   parameters.ToDictionary(a => a.Name, b => b.ParameterType.Name);
     if (obj is Action<string, int>)
         del.DynamicInvoke("foo", 2);
 }
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Action<string, int> act = (x, y) => { Console.WriteLine("x={0}, y= {1}", x, y); };
     InspectDelegate(act);
 }
```

Comment: Messing with strings is a horrible way of doing this; it will also go horribly wrong if someone gives you something that isn't generic (`delInfo[1]` will fail)

Comment: I dropped the _horrible_ parts.

Comment: what is del? in if (!(obj is Delegate del))

Comment: This is "Pattern matching"- a new feature in C# 7.0, it basically create instance of type `Delegate` and set its value to the `obj` if it satisfy the expression `obj is Delegate` . 
see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/